# Porque quando faço a importação dos dados com pd.read_html a virgula some?

Tags: html, python, pandas, web-scraping

Tentando jogar os dados para um dataFrame, mas estou tendo problemas com a formatação dos números.
o código é bem simples

```
url = 'http://ipeadata.gov.br/ExibeSerie.aspx?stub=1&serid32099=32099&serid32102=32102&serid33593=33593&serid33595=33595&serid33596=33596&serid33663=33663'
df = pd.read_html(str(url),header=0,decimal=',')[2]

print(df)



>    Data        Taxa de cÃ¢mbio   0    1944.01           NaN           
> 1    1944.02           NaN            2    1944.03           NaN      
> 3    1944.04           NaN            4    1944.05           NaN      
> ..       ...           ...            941  2022.06       52374.0      
> 942  2022.07       51878.0            943  2022.08       51784.0      
> 944  2022.09       54060.0            945  2022.10       52564.0
```

o numero correto por exemplo em 2022.10 seria 5,25640 mas veio dessa forma.

Comment: sobre a questão do decimal=','  Já tentei tbm com '.' e não mudou nada.

Answer (score -1):

```
url = 'http://ipeadata.gov.br/ExibeSerie.aspx?stub=1&serid32099=32099&serid32102=32102&serid33593=33593&serid33595=33595&serid33596=33596&serid33663=33663'
df = pd.read_html(url,thousands= '.')[2]

print(df)
```

O problema era o separador de milhares
thousands= '.'